# how to group by multiindex in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this kind of pandas table

```
   user_id  is_win  behave  trade_count
0   279        0        0          1
1   279        0        1          1
2   279        1        1          1
3   279        0        0          1
4   279        1        0          1
```

how to change this table into this form to sum up the last column

```
 user_id    is_win  behave  trade_count
    279        0        0          1
                        1          1
               1        0          2
                        1          1
```

Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby(['user_id', 'is_win', 'behave']).trade_count.sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`df2 = df.groupby(['user_id', 'is_win', 'behave'])['trade_count'].agg('sum').reset_index()`